# Is it possible to search MediaWiki sites using regular expressions?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, regex

I'd like to search for phrases using regular expressions on sites such as Wikipedia and Wikimedia Commons. Is it possible to do this?

Example regex search query: (facebook|google) (corporate history|websites)

It's already possible to do the same on Google ([as demonstrated here](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%28google+OR+yahoo+OR+microsoft%29&oq=%28google+OR+yahoo+OR+microsoft%29&gs_l=hp.3...4468.6753.1.6993.13.13.0.0.0.1.199.925.12j1.13.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.l5AHaCiM9dc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.dmg&fp=dc8abc04c054405e&biw=1366&bih=639)), so I want to know whether it's possible for Wikipedia as well.

Comment: Would you be willing to download several gigabytes of data and do all of the filtering on your own computer?

Comment: It appears that is possible to do this using AutoWikiBrowser: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AutoWikiBrowser/Regular_expression

Comment: You can use AWB to search a certain page (or a set of pages), but not the whole wiki, which I was assuming is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to search the entire wiki. Are there any tools on the toolserver for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's available and powered by the [CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch) (based on [ElasticSearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch)) which is the used search engine in the MediaWiki sites, and the Wikimedia platform.

## Some usage examples:

***Note:*** Full guide reference, and source - on Wikipedia: [Help:Searching#Search_string_syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Searching#Search_string_syntax).

### As for your question:

> **Logical operators**
>
> The search engine supports boolean logic in searches. The logical operators include the "-" (minus sign) character for "logical not", the AND, the OR, and the grouping parentheses brackets: (_).
>
> Logical OR must be spelled in capital letters; the AND operator is assumed for all terms (separated by spaces), but capital AND is equivalent.

### More examples:

- Simple `AND`, `OR`: `"credit card" OR "payment card"`, `"credit card" AND "payment card"` - will work as expected.
- Suffixed tilde character for fuzzy search ("sounds like") - For example, searching for `charlie~ parker~` returns `Charlie Parker`, `Charles Palmer`, `Charley Parks` (up to two character difference, not including the first one).
- Wildcard search - searching `face*e` - starts with `face` and ends with an `e` with anything in the middle.
  [image]

## Extra reading

Read more about the [search engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Searching#Search_string_syntax) and this [extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch) to unveil their full functionality and features.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to search Wikipedia (or any other site that a search engine can access) using simple regular expressions, as long as you rely on an search engine. The following Google search query searches Wikipedia for matches of the regular expression `(Yahoo|Google|Microsoft)`:

https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:en.wikipedia.org+(google+OR+yahoo+OR+microsoft)&oq=site:en.wikipedia.org+(google+OR+yahoo+OR+microsoft)&gs_l=hp.3...87411.96861.2.97076.26.24.2.0.0.0.79.1141.24.24.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.s2oGD_2LKy4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.dmg&fp=dc8abc04c054405e&biw=1366&bih=639

Comment: A normal search with boolean operators is just a very tiny subset of regular expression search capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in doing a regex search of Wikipedia *titles*, Crossword Nexus allows you to do that.  http://crosswordnexus.com/wiki